# C# Connection String Error

Tags: c#, sql

```
     SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
```

This is the connection String 
Unrecognized escape sequence
a red underline under S in this part (PC\SQL)

Answer (score 4):

Use `@` beginning of your connection string.`Backslash` is a special character.You need to escape it using double backslashes like `"\\"`. or you can use `@` to make it [`verbatim string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
@"Data Source=MOE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
```

Comment: I did that anad it works but i cant find culomns in database

Comment: @Moeprogrammer I'm sorry, that is completely a different question.I can't help you.If you have another question ask another question

Comment: ok this is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312151/c-sharp-i-cant-find-culomns-of-database

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the @ before you begin the string or escape the \ character with another \ character like:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
```