# I can't find columns of database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CSharpApp.Classes
{

  public class RegistrationClass
  {
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOE-   PC\\SQLEXPRESS;   InitialCatalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    ConnectionClass con = new ConnectionClass();

    String fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress,  schoolDegree, languages, highSchool, faculty, major;



    public void setValues (String fullName1,String motherName1,String gender1,String placeOfBirth1,String email1,String phone1,String adress1, String faculty1,String major1,String schoolDegree1,String languages1,String highSchool1)
    {

        fullName = fullName1;
        motherName = motherName1;
        gender = gender1;
        placeOfBirth= placeOfBirth1;
        email =email1;
        phone= phone1;
        adress =adress1;
        faculty =faculty1;
        major =major1;
        schoolDegree =schoolDegree1;
        languages =languages1;
        highSchool = highSchool1;
    }

    public void  InsertStudentInfo()
    {
        String query = "Insert into StudentInfo( fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress,schoolDegree, languages, highSchool) values( fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress,schoolDegree, languages, highSchool) ";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();

    }

    public void  InsertUniversityInfo()
    {

        String query = "Insert into universityInfo( faculty,major) Values (faculty, major)";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        con.openConnection();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

I can't find the columns of the database table. I don't know why

> Invalid column name 'motherName'.
>   Invalid column name 'gender'.
>   Invalid column name 'placeOfBirth'.
>   .....

Comment: It's hard to comment without seeing the database schema.

Comment: should you not be passing values into the methods `InsertStudentInfo()` and `InsertUniversityInfo()`? also where is your select statement? does the `InsertStudentInfo()` void actually run?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Icant ask more questions !!! why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query seems to be broken in two ways...

First, as the error indicates, those columns apparently don't exist on that table.  Check the schema of the `StudentInfo` table.  No matter how sure you are that it's correct, the SQL query engine is *usually* right about these things.

Second, what are you actually inserting?  Look at your query:

```
Insert into StudentInfo (fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress,schoolDegree, languages, highSchool)
                 values (fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, adress,schoolDegree, languages, highSchool)
```

Are you trying to insert the values that are *already in the table*?  What data are you actually trying to insert?  You just reference the same columns in the `VALUES` clause that you did in the `INTO` clause.  Even if this works, I guarantee it won't do what you expect it to do, whatever that is.  You need to provide *values* to insert into the database.  Without values to be inserted, what are you trying to do?

If you're trying to insert the values that are in this object, you need to add those as parameters.  First, adjust the query:

```
Insert into StudentInfo (fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, address, schoolDegree, languages, highSchool)
                 values (@fullName, @motherName, @gender, @placeOfBirth, @email, @phone, @adress, @schoolDegree, @languages, @highSchool)
```

Note the addition of the `@` characters to indicate that the word is a placeholder for a parameter.  Then you need to add the parameters to the command:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motherName", motherName);
// and so on for the rest of the parameters...
```

Finally, as a side note, you shouldn't share connection objects across multiple actions like this.  It's inviting resource leaks and other errors.  Instead, create (and subsequently destroy) the connection object close to where it's used, keeping it alive for as little time as possible:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOE-   PC\\SQLEXPRESS;   InitialCatalog=db_University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
{
    String query = "Insert into StudentInfo (fullName, motherName, gender, placeOfBirth, email, phone, address, schoolDegree, languages, highSchool) values (@fullName, @motherName, @gender, @placeOfBirth, @email, @phone, @adress, @schoolDegree, @languages, @highSchool)";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motherName", motherName);
    // and so on for the rest of the parameters...
    myConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it works . But i have an error : 'Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog''

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as **literals** or SQL Server **variables** - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

So either you need to use the `VALUES(...)` approach and have literals or SQL Server variables (starting with a `@`) at hand - or you need to use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach to refer to other columns in your database table(s). Pick one - right now, your `INSERT` statement is really neither of those two valid options